# Change the animation starting point in ArcProgress for android

Tags: android

I am using **lzyzsd/CircleProgress** library in my project and use **ArcProgress** . I want to change the starting direction of the aimation. Here I am using two ArcProgress side by side.

Code...

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/firstLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_270sdp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_200sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_40sdp">

                    <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.ArcProgress
                        android:id="@+id/general_progress"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
                        app:arc_progress="60"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                        android:rotation="90"
                        app:arc_angle="180"
                        app:arc_bottom_text_size="0sp"
                        app:arc_stroke_width="@dimen/_8sdp"
                        app:arc_suffix_text_size="0sp"
                        app:arc_text_color="@color/redPrimary"
                        app:arc_text_size="0sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/generalAchPerTxt"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_above="@+id/genLabel"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_40sdp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_30ssp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/genLabel"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_30sdp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_12sdp"
                        android:text="General"
                        android:textColor="@color/redPrimary"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_16ssp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/generalAchTxt"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@id/genLabel"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_40sdp"
                        android:textColor="@color/redPrimary"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_18ssp" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/generalTargetTxt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/redPrimary"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_24ssp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_200sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_40sdp">

                    <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.ArcProgress
                        android:id="@+id/life_progress"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layoutDirection="ltr"
                        android:rotation="270"
                        app:arc_angle="180"
                        app:arc_bottom_text_size="0sp"
                        app:arc_stroke_width="@dimen/_8sdp"
                        app:arc_suffix_text_size="0sp"
                        app:arc_text_color="@color/redPrimary"
                        app:arc_text_size="0sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lifeAchPerTxt"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_above="@+id/lifeLabel"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_40sdp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_30ssp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lifeLabel"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_30sdp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                        android:text="Life"
                        android:textColor="@color/norOrange"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_16ssp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lifeAchTxt"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/lifeLabel"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_40sdp"
                        android:textColor="@color/norOrange"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_18ssp" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lifeTargetTxt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@color/norOrange"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_24ssp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Here I want to change the first ArcProgress's animation(general_progress) starting from Bottom to top..Because it is starting from top to bottom. Second one (life_progress) working ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the XML try to set the angle to -270

```
app:arc_angle="-270"
```

Then it will start from the end and to go the other side